# How to extract value from children's in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a collection based on interface below

```
interface ITurbine {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  turbine: ITurbine[];
}
```

collection can have very deep values with same structure.

How can I extract all children in one list with one level

pseudo exampleTurbines

```
[
{id:1, name:test1, turbine:null},
{id:2, name:test2, turbine:[
                            id:3, name:test3, turbine: {id:4, name:test4, turbine:null}    
                            id:5, name:test5, turbine: {id:6, name:test6, turbine:null}   
                    ]},
]
```

expected result is to extract all turbines in one array

```
[
{id:1, name:test1},
{id:2, name:test2},
..
{id:6, name:test6}
]


const getInLineTurbineArray = (turbines: ITurbine[]): ITurbine[] => {
  let inlineTurbines: ITurbine[] = [];
  inlineTurbines.forEach((turbine) => {
    var test = extractTurbines(turbine);
    inlineTurbines.push(test)
  });
  return inlineTurbines;
};

const extractTurbines = (turbines: ITurbine) => {
  if (turbines.turbine) {
    turbines.turbine.forEach((child) => {
      return extractTurbines(child);
    });
  } else {
    return turbines;
  }
};
```

Comment: So the first pointer is that `forEach` does not return results.  You will want to use `map` to return all the collected results.  And since you are recursively going down a tree, you will most likely want to flatten the results as you collect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you re trying to accomplish is called "flattening" and specifically flattening  a Tree-like structure where a Node( a Turbine) can have 0..n leafs(other turbines). You can try to use recursion to work with structures like that.

```
const tree = [
  {id:1, name:"test1", turbine:null},
  {id:2, name:"test2", turbine:[
      {id:3, name:"test3", turbine: {id:4, name:"test4", turbine:null}},
      {id:5, name:"test5", turbine: {id:6, name:"test6", turbine:null}}   
    ]
  },
]

function flattenTree(tree) {
  let result = [];

  if(Array.isArray(tree)) {
    for(const node of tree) {
      result.push(
        {id: node.id, name: node.name}
      );

      if(node.turbine) {
        result = result.concat(flattenTree(node.turbine));
      }
    }
  } else {
    result.push({id: tree.id, name: tree.name})
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(flattenTree(tree))
```

while trying to come up with a solution I also saw that the example object you gave looks more like this interface:

```
interface ITurbine {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  turbine?: ITurbine | ITurbine[];
}
```

I don't know if this was a typo on your end but the solution should probably work either way.